# Trim quotes from read-host directory stored as variable

Tags: powershell, path, rename, quotes, trim

I have a small Powershell script I wrote to help rename folders of files, based off the filenames in another folder.

I have two read-host lines that catch the input from the user and store the input as the source folder and destination folder as strings. This makes life easier as I can drag and drop rather than full typing the path.

The problem is that Powershell keeps throwing errors, saying it can't find the drive "X:
This seems to be being caused by the quotes around the path, as removing them after dragging and dropping works fine.

Here is how it is captured:

```
$source = Read-Host "Source folder"
$destination = Read-Host "Destination folder"
[array]$a = Get-ChildItem $source
[array]$b = Get-ChildItem $destination
```

What is the easiest way to remove the quotes from those strings, before running the Get-ChildItem command? I have tried things like $source.replace, $_. trim and also $source -replace ('"', "")

Can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the invalid strings you try to remove quotes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes, like so:

```
PS C:\> $foo = 'x:\"some weird\path"'
PS C:\> $foo
x:\"some weird\path"
PS C:\> $foo.Replace('"', '')
x:\some weird\path
PS C:\> $foo -replace '"', ''
x:\some weird\path
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure what went wrong, but I tried the $foo.replace method once more (after several failed attempts) and it worked perfectly.